# Vaadin containerFilter select null field

Tags: java, vaadin

I am using `com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.query.TableQuery` to populate a UI view with data from a MYSQL table.

I would like to only show rows where a specific field is null, so the raw SQL is:

`SELECT * FROM products WHERE monthsLeft IS null;`

Referencing the [Vaadin docs](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/sqlcontainer.filteringsorting.html#sqlcontainer.filteringsorting.filtering), I am using Vaadin SQLContainer object to set this criteria as
`sqlContainer.addContainerFilter(new Compare.Equal("monthsLeft ", null));`

But this throws the following error:

`Sep 11, 2014 5:10:13 PM com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault
SEVERE: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot add null parameters using addParamaters(Object). Use addParameters(Object,Class) instead
    at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.query.generator.StatementHelper.addParameterValue(StatementHelper.java:63)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.query.generator.filter.CompareTranslator.getWhereStringForFilter(CompareTranslator.java:32)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.query.generator.filter.QueryBuilder.getWhereStringForFilter(QueryBuilder.java:82)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.query.generator.filter.QueryBuilder.getJoinedFilterString(QueryBuilder.java:92)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.query.generator.filter.QueryBuilder.getWhereStringForFilters(QueryBuilder.java:107)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.query.generator.DefaultSQLGenerator.generateSelectQuery(DefaultSQLGenerator.java:107)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.query.TableQuery.getCount(TableQuery.java:200)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.SQLContainer.updateCount(SQLContainer.java:1142)
    at com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.SQLContainer.size(SQLContainer.java:398)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractSelect.size(AbstractSelect.java:762)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.refreshRenderedCells(Table.java:1628)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.getVisibleCells(Table.java:3921)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Table.beforeClientResponse(Table.java:3155)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlWriter.write(UidlWriter.java:96)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.writeUidl(UidlRequestHandler.java:149)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:97)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:37)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1329)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:236)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)`

I was hoping there was an `Compare.IsNull` but I don't see one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started looking at the source to write a patch and I found com.vaadin.data.util.filter.**IsNull**.
Solution is:
`sqlContainer.addContainerFilter(new IsNull("monthsLeft"));`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code, this does not seem possible.

This method has no 'IS NULL' case:

```
@Override
public String getWhereStringForFilter(Filter filter, StatementHelper sh) {
    Compare compare = (Compare) filter;
    sh.addParameterValue(compare.getValue());
    String prop = QueryBuilder.quote(compare.getPropertyId());
    switch (compare.getOperation()) {
    case EQUAL:
        return prop + " = ?";
    case GREATER:
        return prop + " > ?";
    case GREATER_OR_EQUAL:
        return prop + " >= ?";
    case LESS:
        return prop + " < ?";
    case LESS_OR_EQUAL:
        return prop + " <= ?";
    default:
        return "";
    }
}
```

And the method referenced (addParameters(Object,Class)) is only called from three methods with the names generateDeleteQuery, generateInsertQuery and generateUpdateQuery.

Shouldn't be too difficult to submit a patch though ;)